# Getting workitems link using TFS C# API

Tags: c#, azure-devops, tfs-sdk

i am new to TFS API and i am using C# code as described in:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/samples?view=azure-devops

I was managed to run the code on my TFS test server and to get the querty result quite easily. However, when i am tryin to get work items links details, i can't find the right way to do it.
When i zom into 1 object during the code executuon, i see that the Links attribute is set to null while the 'real' workitem in TFS as linked WI as parent. Any idea how can I loop thru WI links ang get the linked WI details?
Many thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Post the response you are getting

Comment: Do you use Rest API or SOAP?

Comment: I am using Rest API

Answer (score 4):

You have to set the expand attribute in GetWorkItemAsync:

`GetWorkItemAsync(Id, expand: WorkItemExpand.Relations).Result`

You can find all links in Relations list. Link does not contain an id, but you can extract it from link URL. Parent type is **System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse** value in Rel member. Example of the relations list:

```
var wi = GetWorkItemWithRelations(wiId);

if (wi.Relations != null)
    {
        foreach (var wiLink in wi.Relations)
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-40}: {1}", wiLink.Rel, ExtractWiIdFromUrl(wiLink.Url));
    }

static int ExtractWiIdFromUrl(string Url)
{
    int id = -1;

    string splitStr = "_apis/wit/workItems/";

    if (Url.Contains(splitStr))
    {
        string [] strarr = Url.Split(new string[] { splitStr }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        if (strarr.Length == 2 && int.TryParse(strarr[1], out id))
                return id;
    }

    return id;
}
```

Additional link types you can find here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/link-type-reference?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts

Comment: Can you share with me link to documentaion to read on how to loop thru the links and get to the linked WI? or any general documenation? Thanks again!

Comment: @UziYona All links are contained in WorkItemRelation list of WorkItem class. There is my investigation, maybe they will be useful for you: [Get Work Items](https://oshamrai.wordpress.com/2018/09/11/vsts-rest-api-2-get-work-items/), [Add and Edit Work Item Links](https://oshamrai.wordpress.com/2018/12/21/azure-devops-services-rest-api-7-add-and-edit-work-item-links/)

Comment: Thank you again Aleksander!. However, when i loop thru the relations i do get teh lonks but i do not get hte link type. I get the follwoing relation (link?) example: https://my serverdetails/_apis/wit/workItems/894 and 894 is the linked workitem, but i can't find a way to get the link type (e.g. parent). any ideas?

Comment: @UziYona I`ve updated my answer with the code sample.

Comment: @UziYona Accept as answer to tell all members that your problem was resolved: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers